# Microsoft Excel on save changes decimal point to 8

Tags: c#, excel, decimal, openxml

when i open on save excel the value displayed in excel is 596207726.09 but actual code behind value is 596207726.09000003.

why this change happaned?

But 596207726.09 in excel changed to 596207726.09000003 in code.

How 000003 getting added in code and how to solve the issue in c# code so it can take exact decimal point as given in Excel

For Example

1. 596207726.09 - 596207726.09
2. 596207726.092 - 596207726.092

Comment: How are you getting this in code? The OpenXML SDK will just give you a string, as far as I remember.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Understanding Floating Point Precision, aka “Why does Excel Give Me Seemingly Wrong Answers?”](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/#:~:text=The%20precision%20of%20a%20number,within%2015%20digits%20of%20precision.)

Comment: This happens because `596207726.09` cannot be represented exactly as a double-precision floating point number, so what's stored is the nearest approximation. When the value is displayed, rounding takes care of not showing the excess digits, but that doesn't change the fact that the exact value is not `596207726.09` but `596207726.09000003`. Your code either needs to round these values as well (note that `Double.ToString()` will round by default, much like Excel does), or else the value needs to be stored in Excel as text (but then you lose the ability to calculate with it, obviously).